# Remove a blank legend from excel spreadsheet

Tags: excel, vba, plot, legend, excel-charts

I have the following table the results of which will change depending on a dropdown list:

[image]

The module that I call in my VBA code for plotting this graph is as follows:

```
Option Explicit

Sub GraphOn()
    
    Sheet1.Activate
    
    If ActiveSheet.ChartObjects.Count > 0 Then
        Sheet1.ChartObjects.Delete
    End If
    
    Sheet1.Range("H2:L49").Select
    
    Sheet1.Shapes.AddChart2(227, xlLine).Select
    
    With Sheet1.ChartObjects(1).Chart
        ' remove default chart title
        .HasTitle = True
        .ChartTitle.Caption = "=DoNotModify!R2C15"
    
    End With
    
End Sub
```

which works like a charm, however, I end up with an empty legend for the years series (see below).
[image]

What should I incorporate in my code to remove this empty legend? Thanks

Comment: `Sheet1.ChartObjects(1).Chart.FullSeriesCollection(3).Formula = ""`. Your problem comes because the selected range includes the L (third) column, which is empty. This code removes the 3rd lines of the graphics, efectively reducing the source range to H2:K49. of course you can also edit the `Sheet1.Range("H2:K49").Select` line.

Comment: @AntoineL Of course!!!! How did I miss that! Thank you!